# implement "X PRIMARY selection event monitor"

Tags: x11, xlib, xorg

I am learning some principles of X, and I want to know how to listen selection event of Xlib and transfer text selected of the application.

I read the mannul from 
https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/
https://github.com/python-xlib/python-xlib 
and as a newbie that is too complex for me.

I have no plan to try gtk+ and Qt and others which lead to extra dependencies.

so please give me some advice or a demo if could, thanks.